# Ruby on Rails: Using shovel operator to update a string attribute on a model does not make the model dirty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We ran into an interesting problem today.  It seems that if you use the shovel operator to concatenate a string attribute on an ActiveRecord model, it doesn't make the model dirty.  For example:

```
e = Employee.first
e.name << "asdf"
e.name_changed? # returns false
e.changed? # returns false
```

This makes sense since the shovel operator updates a string without making a copy of it, where the += operator will make a copy of the string.  I don't see how ActiveRecord could possibly know that something changed if you use the shovel operator.

Has anyone else seen this?  Is the solution to just use `+=` instead of `<<` when concatenating strings?

Comment: You should submit a bug report to the rails folks if you haven't already.

Comment: no it's not a bug, it's already know and it quiet impossible to avoid

Answer (score 5):

The solution is was you write.

Or you can mark before that your attibute will_change

```
e = Employee.first
e.name_will_change!
e.name << "asdf"
e.name_changed? # => true
```

It's mark on the API documentation. ActiveModel::Dirty

Comment: God, I just love how Ruby code sometimes looks like a real but terse conversation among us and the computer! And we are the boss that give orders, not the slave that fills out dozens of reports (XML?) that the boss will never read anyway.